# Applescript reading file content as 72

Tags: file, applescript

I am trying to make an AppleScript application to read numbers from a text file and put them into an array, the only issue is it is reading it as if the value "72" is in it. To make it simple to debug I am reading and displaying the whole file.

This is my text file:

```
27.19
102
111
```

And here is my AppleScript code:

```
set fileContent to read "/path/to/file"

display dialog fileContent
```

Why is this reading the file content as 72?

Thanks for the help, sorry if this belongs at StackOverflow. I asked it here since it is to do with Apple's own language.

Comment: What text encoding has the text file?

Comment: @vadian This is generated using TextEdit and making it plain text before saving. It is the same way I made a mother file that contains words (which worked). I used the default settings, guessing its UTF-8. Not sure.

Comment: If it's UTF-8, you should use this syntax 'set fileContent to read "/path/to/file" as «class utf8»'

Comment: @vadian I now get "27".

Comment: It's a progress, Isn't it? You have three options to read a file: MacRoman (without coercion), UTF-8 (`as class «utf8»`) and UTF-16 (`as Unicode text`)

Comment: @vadian Iy is progress :) . Unicode defiantly isn't what I want, just a symbol. So MacRoman I don't need to do anything to it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, some reason I had to put it in a new folder, not sure why it works, but hey, I fixed it!